# I have been trying to Run a simple Page Object Model in Python with Selenium but for some reason the browser do not open

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

'''
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pytest

#Google.py File
class Google:
txtbox_searchbar_xpath = "//input[@class='gLFyf gsfi']"

```
def __init__(self,driver):
    self.driver = driver

def enterSearchTerm(self,search_term):
    self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, self.txtbox_searchbar_xpath).claer()
    self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, self.txtbox_searchbar_xpath).send_keys(search_term,Keys.RETURN)
```

'''

'''
from selenium import webdriver
from PageObjects.Google import Google
import pytest

#test_Google.py
class Google_Test:

```
url = "https://www.google.com/"
search_word = "Python.org"
searchbar_xpath ="//input[@class='gLFyf gsfi']"

def test_searchGoogle(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\mm195\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe")
    self.driver.get(self.url)
    # Initiate Google Class
    self.google = Google(self.driver)
    self.google.enterSearchTerm(self.search_word)
    act_title = self.driver.title
    if act_title == "Google":
        assert True
    else:
        assert False
```

'''

Comment: Please post a specific error and edit your code to display correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This answer solves only title-question "why the browser is not opening".
Pytest naming convention requires to have Classes and method starting with "Test/test".

So you need to change Class name to Test_Google.

---

**Update - 06/02/2021 - 19:26 PLN Time**

How are you running tests? Pytest has own test discovery mechanism. If you call simply from cmd line:

```
pytest test_script.py
```

then it should discover existing test/tests

---

---

**Update - 08/02/2021 - 12:54 PLN Time**

So

You would need to provide more information:

- directory structure
- errors during firs/second run

Comment: Thanks a lot, its a step forward in fixing the problem. Now pytest runs but can't find any test cases in the file.

Comment: Executing the test with command pytest -v -s (path to python script) doesn't work for me but the command python -m pytest ( path to python script) for me but I'll get a no test found error